# Registration form with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, registration, user-registration

I need a registration form to a page which template is already defined.

- Should have only this fields:
- email
- password

Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WP Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-members/) plugin may be able to help you out.